# bfl on groovy, catkin_make errors and compile errors

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a strange problem with using bfl under ros groovy. I'm using the regular installed bfl package. "roscd bfl" takes me to /opt/ros/groovy/share/bfl which contains a package.xml.

Yet when I include bfl in the find_package() line of my  project's CMakeLists.txt just like any other ros package, catkin_make complains:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package bfl.

  Set bfl_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for bfl.
  The file will have one of the following names:

  bflConfig.cmake
  bfl-config.cmake
```

If I leave out bfl from the find_package() and try to include e.g.

```
#include "bfl/pdf/gaussian.h"
```

the compiler throughs an excessive amount of errors (in total >700) e.g.

```
/opt/ros/groovy/include/bfl/wrappers/matrix/vector_wrapper.h:60: error: reference to 'MatrixWrapper' is ambiguous
```

Any suggestions, ideas what could cause that behaviour?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61648/bfl-on-groovy,-catkin_make-errors-and-compile-errors/) by [SebastianRiedel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3893/sebastianriedel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the problem, used Eigen in one of my classes and the Eigen namespace (Matrix type) collides with BFL. So removing

```
using namespace Eigen;
```

solved the >700 compile errors.

---

Originally posted by [SebastianRiedel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3893/sebastianriedel/) with karma: 16 on 2013-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0